# How to display total count of raw in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4

This is my table **wys_attendence**:

```
id   studid  adate  amonth  ayear  acls_id  attendence      
1    28      02     07      2015   10       1     
2    31      02     07      2015   10       0  
4    32      02     07      2015   10       1   
5    28      30     07      2015   10       0 
6    31      30     07      2015   10       1   
7    32      30     07      2015   10       1   
9    28      31     07      2015   10       1   
10   31      31     07      2015   10       1   
11   32      31     07      2015   10       1   
13   28      06     08      2015   10       1   
14   31      06     08      2015   10       0   
15   32      06     08      2015   10       1   
17   28      07     08      2015   10       0   
18   31      07     08      2015   10       1   
19   32      07     08      2015   10       1   
21   28      08     08      2015   10       1   
22   31      08     08      2015   10       1   
23   32      08     08      2015   10       0   
24   28      12     08      2015   10       1   
25   31      12     08      2015   10       1   
26   32      12     08      2015   10       0
```

how to check sum of each students where  amonth=07 ,ayear=2015  and attendence=1

i got incorrect output  like this

RollNo StudentName  02 13  14  15  16  17  20  Total PresentsTotal Absents

```
28   Gokul        p  p   p  p   a   p   p       5               2

31   Goku         p p   p   a   p   p   p       5               2

32   Gok          p p   p   p   p   a   a       5               2
```

i got last student  count of value attendence=1 and attendence=0

how to all students count of value attendence=1 and attendence=0 separetly.

I want like this

RollNo StudentName  02 13  14  15  16  17  20  Total Presents  TotalAbsents

```
28   Gokul        p  p   p  p   a   p   p       6                 1

31   Goku         p p   p   a   p   p   p       6                 1

32   Gok          p p   p   p   p   a   a       5                 2
```

my controller.php

```
` $attendence_tbl = WysAttendancename::where('cls_id',$id)->first();
        $wys_attendence_table = $attendence_tbl->attendance_name;
        $attendance = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                    ->where('amonth',$amonth)
                    ->where('ayear',$ayear)
                    ->groupBy('adate')
                    ->get();
        $stud_attend = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                    ->where('amonth',$amonth)
                    ->where('ayear',$ayear)
                    ->get();
        foreach($students as $student){
        $cunt1 = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                 ->where('studid',$student->id)
                 ->where('amonth',$amonth)
                 ->where('ayear',$ayear) 
                 ->where('attendence',1)
                 ->count();
            $cunt0 = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
                 ->where('studid',$student->id)
                 ->where('amonth',$amonth)
                 ->where('ayear',$ayear) 
                 ->where('attendence',0)
                 ->count();            
        }`
```

my view.blade.php

```
                 `@foreach($students as $student)                  
                  @if($student->studcls == $id)
                  <tr> <td>{{$student->id}}</td>
                    <td>{{$student->studname}}</td>
                  @foreach($stud_attend as $stud_attends)
                  @if($student->id == $stud_attends->studid)  
                  @if($stud_attends->attendence == 1)
                  <td><font color="green" size="3">p</font></td>
                  @elseif($stud_attends->attendence == 0)
                  <td><font color="red" size="3">a</font></td>   
                  @endif
                  @endif                 
                  @endforeach
                  <td>{{$cunt1}}</td> 
                <td>{{$cunt0}}</td> 
                  </tr>          
                  @endif                 
                  @endforeach`
```

how to solve my problem?

i try to echo method..var_dump($cunt1) i got correct answer int(6) int(6) int(5) and var_dump($cunt0) is int(1) int(1) int(2).

but run on  view.blade.php i got 5 5 5 and 2 2 2 the last value to all studid's.

how to modify my view.blade.php code?

Comment: Is this not nearly word for word a question you asked 3 hours ago? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914551/how-to-display-total-count-of-raw-values-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $attendance = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
            ->whereRaw('amonth = "'.$amonth.'"')
            ->whereRaw('ayear = "'.$ayear.'"')
            ->groupBy('adate')
            ->get();

    $presentsCountQuery = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
            ->select(DB::raw('studid, COUNT(*) AS presents_counter'))
            ->whereRaw('amonth = "'.$amonth.'"')
            ->whereRaw('ayear = "'.$ayear.'"')
            ->whereRaw('attendence = 1')
            ->groupBy('studid')
            ->toSql();

    $absentsCountQuery = DB::table($wys_attendence_table)
            ->select(DB::raw('studid, COUNT(*) AS absents_counter'))
            ->whereRaw('amonth = "'.$amonth.'"')
            ->whereRaw('ayear = "'.$ayear.'"')
            ->whereRaw('attendence = 0')
            ->groupBy('studid')
            ->toSql();

    $stud_attend = DB::table($wys_attendence_table . ' as table')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $presentsCountQuery . ') AS presents_counter_table'), 'table.studid', '=', 'presents_counter_table.studid')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $absentsCountQuery . ') AS absents_counter_table'), 'table.studid', '=', 'absents_counter_table.studid')
            ->where('table.amonth',$amonth)
            ->where('table.ayear',$ayear)
            ->groupBy('table.studid')
            ->get();
    //var_dump($stud_attend);
```

View:

```
@foreach($students as $student)
    @if($student->studcls == $id)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$student->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$student->studname}}</td>
            @foreach($stud_attend as $stud_attends)
                @if($student->id == $stud_attends->studid)
                    @if($stud_attends->attendence == 1)
                        <td><font color="green" size="3">p</font></td>
                    @elseif($stud_attends->attendence == 0)
                        <td><font color="red" size="3">a</font></td>
                    @endif
                    <td>{{$stud_attends->presents_counter}}</td>
                    <td>{{$stud_attends->absents_counter}}</td>
                @endif
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Man, change the full of your code... The where do not work in left join in this format. I tested my solution and it works perfectly. What is your problem with it?

Comment: sir iam not use left join condition in my code .but it work ...but $presentsCountQuery and $absentscountQuery is not work. i want only total count of 'p' and 'a' of each studid's correspondly.i use this code i got sql query in my view page.

Comment: above my controller code is fine its work ..i try to echo method..var_dump($cunt1) i got correct answer int(6) int(6) int(5) and var_dump($cunt0) is int(1) int(1) int(2)..but i dont know how to call on my view page.. but run on view.blade.php i got 5 5 5 and 2 2 2 the last value to all studid's.

how to modify my view.blade.php code?  my view.blade.php code is above.

Comment: I do notbunderstand you. If you would use my solution, you do not have to use queries in view. View is just display. Do not make logic in a view. When you use my solution your $stud_attend will have 2 more properties (presents_counter, absents_counter) I think that is that you want.

Comment: Please check this answer... Than tell me what is the result.

Comment: sir ...iam using your both code....but only display rollno and student name other fields are empty.

Comment: i think this part of codeis not work..... $stud_attend = DB::table($wys_attendence_table . ' as table')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $presentsCountQuery . ') AS presents_counter_table'), 'table.studid', '=', 'presents_counter_table.studid')
            ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $absentsCountQuery . ') AS absents_counter_table'), 'table.studid', '=', 'absents_counter_table.studid')
            ->where('table.amonth',$amonth)
            ->where('table.ayear',$ayear)
            ->groupBy('table.studid')
            ->get();

Comment: oh... no error messages     but its not work properly..when iam use this code i see view page  only <td>{{$student->id}}</td> <td>{{$student->studname}}</td> values . and other values are empty. So i dont know is it right or wrong ,i think this $stud_attend part of controller is not work properly..